# How do I perform a mysql query that is limited by a value in the same table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table 'model_values' that looks like this:

```
+----+------------+-------------+----------------+------------+
| id | value_post | value_model | value_property | value_data |
+----+------------+-------------+----------------+------------+
|  1 |          1 |          39 |              1 | ValueA     |
|  2 |          1 |          39 |              2 | Value1     |
|  3 |          1 |          39 |              3 | 2013       |
|  4 |          2 |          39 |              1 | ValueA     |
|  5 |          2 |          39 |              2 | Value2     |
|  6 |          2 |          39 |              3 | 2012       |
|  7 |          3 |          39 |              1 | ValueB     |
|  8 |          3 |          39 |              2 | Value1     |
|  9 |          3 |          39 |              3 | 2013       |
| 10 |          4 |          30 |              1 | ValueA     |
| 11 |          4 |          30 |              2 | Value2     |
| 12 |          4 |          30 |              3 | 2013       |
+----+------------+-------------+----------------+------------+
```

I'm trying to create a set of drop-downs that show the value_data for value_property's 1 and 2, based on the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM model_values
INNER JOIN models
ON model_values.value_model = models.id
INNER JOIN properties
ON model_values.value_property = properties.id
WHERE model_values.value_property = {$safe_property} && models.id = {$safe_model_id}
GROUP BY model_values.value_data
```

But I want the drop-downs to also be limited by value_property 3 (which is year). So a user will first select the year of 2013, and then get two drop-downs to select from with the following options:

```
Select 1: ValueA/ValueB
Select 2: Value1
```

Or if they chose 2012 first, they'd see:

```
Select 1: ValueA
Select 2: Value2
```

I've tried to come up with queries like:

```
WHERE model_values.value_property = 1 && models.id = 39 && model_values.value_data = 2013
```

But obviously that doesn't work since value_property 1 will never have value_data of 2013.

Or subqueries like:

```
WHERE model_values.value_property = 1 && models.id = 39 && model_values.value_data = (
    SELECT model_values.value_data
    FROM model_values
    WHERE model_values.value_data = 2013
)
```

But that returns more than 1 row.

Is a query like this possible?

Comment: What does the desired result look like? - and provide a sqlfiddle for the above

Comment: Here's a link to a sqlfiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3f3b6/2  

The result would look like the one in the link, but the query would involve limiting it to 2012, so "Value1" shouldn't show up.  

I only know enough about mysql to get in trouble at this point. I assume if I can't get this query to work, I'll have to go back and look how I'm looping through results in my php.

Comment: What I'm gathering is it's not possible with just mysql. I've adjusted my PHP to loop through differently to get the result I was looking for. Not sure if I close or delete this question now?

Comment: I think I'd be tempted to close it - only on the basis that the problem only seems to make sense to you!

Comment: Agreed. I just don't know enough about mysql yet to know how to sort through results correctly. I'd close but looks like I don't have enough points yet.

Answer (score 0):

The following query returns an intermediate result, which begs two questions:

1 How do we know which result belongs to which year?

2 Assuming we wanted `value_data = 2`, what are the criteria for picking `id 5` instead of `id 8`?

```
  SELECT * 
    FROM model_values 
   WHERE value_property = 2 
     AND value_model = 39;

ID VALUE_POST VALUE_MODEL VALUE_PROPERTY VALUE_DATA
2  1          39          2              Value1    
5  2          39          2              Value2 
8  3          39          2              Value2
```

Comment: Unfortunately no, the result needs to be based on value_model (not value_post) and filtered by the year. It should look like http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3f3b6/2, just with the additional filter of some kind that limits it to the year.

Answer (score 0):

your last try was almost right just you got subquery return more then 1 row

replace this

```
     && model_values.value_data = (
```

by

```
 && model_values.value_data IN (
```

and i cant see if its right , because you didnt provide the models table

Comment: I adjusted so it shouldn't need the models table:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3f3b6/26  That's returning 0 for me though.

Comment: this is your simple query , and i dont know why you select value_data = 2012 and then you group by value_data while its just 2012. look this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d3f3b6/42  , and i want say there is no field matched with those conditions. so of course its empty